# Configure/Modify CORS on a Google Forms doc

Tags: cors, google-docs, google-forms

I have a Google form, which is embedded into another site (an elearning subsite on Thinkific.com). The form works fine, when accessed via our subsite (e.g. `https://our-site.thinkific.com/courses/xyz`)

However, we are zero-rating the subsite on mobile networks (making it a free resource for healthcare workers), using Binu (recently rebranded Datafree).

To do this, the urls get converted to a zero-rated subdomain on their system, e.g. the above URL would become something like `https://our-binu-subdomain.datafree.co/courses/xyz`

Binu rewrites the response content from Thinkific replacing all URLs/resource links with the appropriate URL on the datafree subdomain, and then the site is zero-rated (actually, reverse-billed).

On the normal (paid) site, the Google Form gets embedded in an iFrame with the domain `https://docs.google.com/forms/foo`.

But on the datafree site, this will be rewritten to be on the datafree domain, and because of CORS this will now error in loading the required scripts:

[image]

Giving:

[image]

Is there any way, maybe in the Google Forms configuration, that I can add this rewritten domain so the CORS policy can be valid?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### I wouldn't say so

AFAIK, there is no way to do it in Google Forms itself, as it would probably open the door to some security vulnerabilities.

#### Possible Workaround

I wouldn't know how to test this with your setup, but a possible workaround might be using a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) to receive a simple HTTP `POST` request from the data-free site. The web app could then populate a spreadsheet or even submit a form if you wanted it to.

This would involve writing an HTML form to be served on the data-free site, which would then send the HTTP `POST` request on the HTML form `submit` event. This HTML would be essentially a copy of the Google form, so depending on how often you have to change this form this may not be entirely practical. Though I am sure it is possible to write another Apps Script function that can convert a form into HTML, in case this turns out to be the best of the less-than-ideal options open to you!

#### Perhaps file a feature request

Maybe its worth filing a feature request for this to:

> https://issuetracker.google.com/

I don't know about asking for the ability to modify the CORS configuration as that doesn't exactly seem like the type of thing that would be easy or desirable to implement for something at the level of a product like Google Forms (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin), but maybe there is some other workaround that they can offer.

Comment: Thanks. I'd hoped they'd let you configure CORS so you could specify one or two domains your form/s would be allowed on, which would then preserve the security aspect. Writing the middleware app is not really a solution as it's being done by non-techies using the Thinkific/Google interfaces. Otherwise I'd be better off just writing the forms themselves and storing in a db. Plus it can't wait for a feature request. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you have a workspace account then it may be worth getting in touch with support and seeing if there is something they can do in the short term. (not sure why I was down-voted for this answer)